# SystemD Can't get script to start Samba4 Active Directory-Domain Controller (AD-DC) at boot Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, samba, systemd

I built Samba4.4.3 AD-DC on Ubuntu 16.04, and cannot figure out how to script it so I can start the samba service on reboot.

I followed the instructions from here:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2146198

I did not use the install from the Ubuntu software, or the repositories, because I am building an Active Directory Domain controller, this requires more than just Samba, and more than the standard install in the repositories builds.

and I also tried his answer for the problem from here:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2132259

I have also created systemd service files to try and start this, but nothing has worked.

If anyone knows how to get Samba to start at boot on 16.04, please contact me right away, thanks in advance for your help.

Chris

Comment: Didi you enable the service? systemctl enable smb

Comment: Yes it has been tried, and failed, because this is a manual install of Samba, that service is not automatically installed, so it needs to be built.  But I have followed the last link and other things to create the service, and none of them work.  I still really need an answer to this.

Comment: @Videonauth Do you have any incite to this problem, I offered 50 points for an answer, but not getting much movement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After failing to find the answer to my question, and Bounty, I posted my question at:

https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/295108

actionparsnip gave the best answer, and it was to edit /etc/rc.local and add this command just before the exit 0 line

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

edited the file to include:

```
exec /usr/local/samba/sbin/samba -D
exit 0
```

This is the best answer, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple systemd script that works for me at [AskChief](http://www.askchief.org/samba4-systemd-script/).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/612697)

Answer (score 0):

Samba in ubuntu 16.04 and in debian 8/9 works perfectly fine as an AD Domain Controller since Debian and Ubuntu ship Heimdal Kerberos.

You have to build yourself on many other Distributions since they do not include heimdal, only MIT Kerberos.